# Silver Searcher - How to ignore a file

Tags: powershell, cmd, ag

According to the docs, it should be

```
--ignore PATTERN
```

I have a file containing tags, named "tags". I have tried the following, each of them still searches through the tag file..

```
ag -Qt --ignore ".*tags" "asdf"

ag -Qt --ignore .*tags "asdf"

ag -Qt --ignore "tags" "asdf"

ag -Qt --ignore tags "asdf"

ag -Qt --ignore *tags
```

and none of them works.

If I use what's suggested [here](http://minimul.com/ignoring-files-with-ag-silver-searcher.html), then ag doesn't accept it at all

I tried to work around it by renaming it to temp.tags and using `*.tags` pattern to try and ignore it, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some research, it seems that it is a known issue documented [here](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/245). Where if you do an --all-text (-t) search it'll override --ignore since it's searching for all texts. This issue is present for --unrestricted too.

Comment: I found this answer combined with the answer from @ArturMałecki covered why --ignore didn't work for me.

Answer (score 44):

Put the list of files to exclude in `.agignore`.

Note: as @DenilsonSáMaia mentioned, `.agignore` will be deprecated in favor of `.ignore` 
[geoff.greer.fm/2016/09/26/ignore](http://geoff.greer.fm/2016/09/26/ignore)

Comment: Great answer. For more details on .agignore see: https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/wiki/Advanced-Usage

Comment: `.agignore` will be deprecated in favor of `.ignore`: http://geoff.greer.fm/2016/09/26/ignore/

Comment: `.agignore` works with ag version 2.0.0, check source https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/blob/e5230abd98633e9bd408dfec9d26df30db09334b/src/options.c#L681

Comment: you can add the .ignore file globally as ~/.ignore too (rather than at the project root level). Alternatively, you can add the file or folder to exclude to .gitignore instead.

Comment: `.agignore` is the correct file. It's 2021, and it hasn't deprecated yet.. likely never will. `.ignore` would be a terrible name anyway, as you wouldn't really know what it belongs to, and there'd be a likelihood of another app using it.

Comment: I just tried using `.agignore` (with ag 2.2.0) and it didn't work; renaming it to `.ignore` worked.

Comment: @anol I had the opposite behaviour with the same version of `ag` as you (2.2.0) on OS X. (c.f. https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/1097) Not sure what is going on!

Comment: The thing I always miss when setting up on a new computer is that you must place the `.agignore` in the _home directory_ (i.e. `~/.agignore`) not in the root of your application.

Comment: .ignore works in the root of the application

Answer (score 22):

Add just multiple --ignore, at least this works for me:

```
ag -Qt --ignore ".*tags" --ignore asdf
```

If you don't put quotes it's interpreted as directory if you put quotes as PATTERN

Answer (score 17):

I've found that `--ignore` doesn't take a regex.

This should help:

```
ag --ignore="*_test.rb" "SomeAwesomeClass"
```

Comment: This is the behavior that I see as well.  Your comment helped me the most.  It seems to treat the string as a glob pattern if it has special characters and as a literal directory if it doesn't.  Quotes don't seem to change it's behavior at all

Answer (score 5):

As of v2.2.0 (most likely earlier versions as well; I'm just going off the version I have) all these answers don't seem to work. What did work for me was:

```
ag searchterm --ignore=*.log --ignore=*.txt
```

Note the `=` after the `ignore` option.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create .ignore files to ignore things that are in your source repository. .ignore uses the same patterns as .gitignore and .hgignore. Using .ignore can drastically improve search speeds. .

If you want a global .ignore file, consider adding this alias:

```
alias ag='ag --ignore ~/.ignore'
```

to your `~/.bash_profile` (or similar) file. there is also

to temporarily disable vcs ignores you can run with `--skip-vcs-ignores`

Comment: `--path-to-ignore ~/.ignore` did not work for me. `--ignore=~/.ignore` does.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the following works (in `ag` version 0.18.1):

```
ag --ignore TAGS;*.pdf;*.json "search_term"
```

Answer (score 1):

I just placed .agignore file into my user root folder and it works.

> By  default,  ag  will  ignore  files  matched  by  patterns  in
> .gitignore, .hgignore, or .agignore. These files can be anywhere in
> the directories being searched. Ag also  ignores files  matched by the
> svn:ignore property in subversion repositories. **Finally, ag looks in
> $HOME/.agignore for ignore patterns.** Binary files are ignored by
> default as well.

https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ag.1.html

Answer (score 0):

I tried the link you posted (using a glob instead of regex), but removed the '=' sign, and it worked.

Comment: I can't reproduce getting globs to work with this.  Could you post the actual line that worked for you?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using single quotes? I know i've definitely been stumped by using double quotes and no quotes only to find that single quotes worked.

```
ag -Qt --ignore '*tags'
```

Comment: why do your single quotes look like backticks?